# Android app for bluetooth communication with arduino

Tags: android

I need to test my android program by sending strings to my PC with bluetooth communication.

I have found this app which exactly sends strings to an arduino

http://www.elecfreaks.com/829.html

Can i send strings to my PC with this app without using arduino ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Java application to act as Bluetooth server and using it for testing with you Bluetooth client app.

You will need to [Bluecove library](http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.62/) for this, here is an example code snippet:

```
UUID serialUUID = new UUID("1101", true);
String SERVICE_URL = "btspp://localhost:" + serialUUID
        + ";name=My Bluetooth Server;authorize=false;authenticate=false";

StreamConnectionNotifier connectionNotifier = 
                          (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(SERVICE_URL);

System.out.println("Server is waiting for client ... \n URL=" + SERVICE_URL);

// Wait until client connects i.e. a blocking method
StreamConnection connection = connectionNotifier.acceptAndOpen();

RemoteDevice remoteDevice = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(connection);
System.out.println("Client connected: "+remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress());

// Communicate with the device using the below I/O streams
InputStream iStream = connection.openInputStream();
OutputStream oStream = connection.openOutputStream();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have e USB CC2540 BLE kit. Can i also use that?

Comment: You can try it, just make sure that it is working on your PC i.e.driver installed and can pair. Then try the Java code